# Json data how to pass in to DataTable using Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, datatables

i am creating simple crud system using jsp. data passing through json format i tested through console it is passing well but data  is not display on the datatable.i don't why. i wrote what i tried so far.

**Table**

```
<table id="tbl-projects" class="table table-responsive table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
 </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
get_all()
 function get_all()
 {
     $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();
     $('#etbl-projects').DataTable().ajax.reload();
     $.ajax({
         url : "all_project.jsp",
         type : "GET",
         dataType : "JSON",
         success:function(data)
         {      
             alert(data.course);
             $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                 "aaData": data,
                 "scrollX": true,
                 "aoColumns": [
                     {"sTitle": "StudentName", "mData": "name"},
                     {"sTitle": "Course", "mData": "course"},
                     {"sTitle": "Fee", "mData": "fee"},                
                     {
                         "sTitle": "Edit",
                         "mData": "id",
                         "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
                             return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="get_project_details(' + mData + ')">Edit</button>';
                          }
                     },
                     {
                         "sTitle": "Delete",
                         "mData": "id",
                         "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
                             return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="Remove_details(' +  mData + ')">Delete</button>';
                          }
                     }
                 ]
             });

         },
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             alert(xhr);
             console.log(xhr.responseText);


             $('#save').prop('disabled', false);
             $('#save').html('');
             $('#save').append('Save');
         }
     });
 }

</script>
```

**all_project.jsp** 
**Jsp Page**

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studcrud", "root","");
    String query="select * from records";  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next())
    {    
        String id   =rs.getString("id");
        String name   =rs.getString("name");
        String course   =rs.getString("course");
        String fee   =rs.getString("fee"); 

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", name);
        json.put("course", course);
        json.put("fee", fee);
        json.put("id", id);
        out.print(json);
        out.flush();      

    }

%>
```

i have tested through the console result. screen shot below

```
{"fee":"10000","name":"john","course":"java","id":"1"}{"fee":"7000","name":"Raja","course":"C#","id":"2"}{"fee":"2323","name":"sad","course":"asd","id":"3"}{"fee":"12000","name":"Nishan","course":"Jsp","id":"4"}
```

i have attached the Datatable image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9C5X.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your response in JSON format is invalid (missing comas between object).

Use `org.json.simple.JSONArray` to create a list of objects, for example:

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>

...

JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

while(rs.next())
{    
    String id     = rs.getString("id");
    String name   = rs.getString("name");
    String course = rs.getString("course");
    String fee    = rs.getString("fee"); 

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", name);
    obj.put("course", course);
    obj.put("fee", fee);
    obj.put("id", id);

    list.put(obj);
}

out.print(list.toJSONString());
out.flush();
```

Comment: sir  list.put(obj); here i got the error of  cannot find the symbol and and this lne also get error out.print(list.toJSONString());

Comment: it has only one problem  sir. table loading success. data is loop.only one row record shown.